# Setting bean property before opening Primefaces dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to achieve this functionality.

```
<p:column>
    <p:commandLink value="prihlasit" oncomplete="dlg.show();" 
                   action="#{signForProjectBean.setProjectForDetail(item)}" />
</p:column>
```

I think is pretty clear what I am trying to do, I would like to display detail of the row in dataTable on which user have clicked. So my approach is to set property of current row to bean and then show the detail in dialog. But it is not working and I am feeling that I am doing something really wrong:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the dialog component is supposed to display the selected item, then you need to ajax-udpate the dialog's content before opening it. Otherwise it will still display the old content as it was when the page is rendered for the first time.

```
<p:commandLink value="prihlasit" update=":dlg" oncomplete="dlg.show();" 
               action="#{signForProjectBean.setProjectForDetail(item)}" />

...

<p:dialog id="dlg" ...>
```